# How to deploy Visual Studio template for dotnet core 6 and angular to azure

Tags: angular, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am using the latest .net core 6 application template with angular and identity from visual studio 2022.  I am able to run everything fine locally.  I have also created an azure database for the identity management.  When I run my application locally while pointing to the azure database everything works fine.

I have created an azure app service using the .net 6 runtime.  I published my application to the app service.

My issue is that when I run the app on azure, I get this error:

```
[application name] is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

How can I troubleshoot this and what might I be missing in my azure setup?

I essentially did exactly what is detailed here except for the code modifications: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/easily-create-spa-with-net-6-0-and-angular-13-and-deploy-to-azure/

Answer (score 0):

We have deployed ***.Net CORE*** and ***angular*** to azure without any issues and it's up and running.

***Output Screenshot:***

[image]

> [application name] is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500

Thanks to ***@Manoj Choudhari's*** [blog](https://thecodeblogger.com/2020/05/16/publish-net-core-angular-app-in-azure/),

> To get the detailed exception, add
> ***app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()*** in `startup.cs`  Configure method.

In your ***Application*** => ***ClientApp*** folder => ***angular.json*** file, change the `outputPath` to `dist`, redeploy the app once again and check it.

***`angular.json` code file:***
[image]

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.  My problem turns out to be related to certificate configurations on my azure app service.  I was able to see the error after using `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()`.  `InvalidOperationException: No signing credential is configured by the 'IdentityServer:Key' configuration section.` So now, I'm trying to troubleshoot this.

Comment: .AddDeveloperSigningCredential() method in `ConfigureServices` section.